# Was hired as Full stack developer but got to work in Low code tools

Tags: job-change, skills

I was a Java plus AWS developer along with handson experience in UI development  in my previous company for 5 years. I switched to new company where I was hired as a full stack developer but the work which I am doing is completely different. I am using all LOW CODE tools to create solutions and POCs which I am not interested to work in.
Just to stay in the same reputed company I have now spent over  2 years but my passion for Programming and Java has not gone.
I am NOT INTERESTED in using these low code Automation tools for development. I tried to tell my interest to management also but it seems of no use.
Now I have almost forgotten Coding also.
How should I switch back to a programming job now and if I switch also do I need to show my current experience?
I am really frustrated since my skillset changed. Can you please help in giving suggestions.

Comment: You need to work on your own personal project outside of working hours. That's the only way you're going to get out of this. And don't wait, the longer you wait, the more difficult it's going to be.

Comment: Okay Stephan. I will do that. That's the only way left now.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to communicate your career goals, and investigate what it will take to realize them while working with your current employer. This might involve looking at internal job postings to see where you might find a better fit.

If that doesn't work out, or the timeline to reach your goals is longer than you'd like, then the next step is to start looking at opportunities beyond your current employment. Consider contributing to open source projects, freelance consulting work / bounties, and of course interviewing for a position that is inline with your goals & passions.

If you decide to look for another full-time position, then you'll need to tune up your resume / portfolio. Re-compile it to suit the job you want, describing under "relevant experience" your current and past roles in terms of how they are relevant for the position you're applying for.

You don't "lose" coding skills when they're not used; you just lose some familiarity. A new position will inevitably have some kind of onboarding process to learn their stack, tooling and code-base. Proficiency will return quickly through that process.

Even if it wasn't enjoyable, what you've learned & worked on over the last two years is a different perspective & layer of understanding, which should inform & enhance your value working in a preferred (Java AWS & UI, etc.) development stack. For example, you now have a deep understanding as a user of low code environments, which would be *extremely* valuable working with a company to develop & extend those products using Java. Or even working with your current employer, to develop domain-specific plug-ins or extensions.

Comment: Thank u Ian. Can I work on improving my coding skills again in these 6 months and start applying for jobs outside ? I am little scared to again and again communicate the same thing to my manager in a more polished way..

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you boss checks in on a regular basis with you to see how you are going. We're I'm from we call them 1:1's and we usually conduct them once of twice a month, personally I prefer every couple of weeks especially with the current remote work arrangements. If your boss doesn't currently do this request a meeting to discuss your current role.

Hopefully you still have your job description, otherwise request a copy from People & Culture/Human Resources. Walk your boss through the job description and highlight how it differs from you current role. If your boss still show's no interest then raise it with someone from People & Culture/Human Resources.

However you may need to consider this is not the right company for you and spend some time updating you CV. There's usually more development roles available then there are quality candidates to fill them, so any developer with 7 years experience shouldn't have to much trouble securing a new role.